# How to do a Select based on content of a XML Column with wildcard

Tags: sql-server, xquery, wildcard

I try to retrieve all the rows from a table that depend on the content of a XML column. Plus the fact that the content corresponds to a pattern.

The layout of my table might look something like this:

```
|Id |Name|Designation|XML             |
| 1 |Abc |Ghi        |...|
| 2 |Def |Jkl        |...|
```

Let's say that a content of XML column could be this:

```
<Root>
  <Node1>
    <SubNode1 />
    <SubNode2 />
  </Node1>
  <Node2>
    <SubNode3 property="Something">
      ...
    </SubNode3>
    <SubNode3 property="Reference.Object(abcdef12345 (1)).Value">
      ...
    </SubNode3>
    <SubNode3 property="SomethingElse">
      ...
    </SubNode3>
  </Node2>
</Root>
```

Now, the previous XML is the content of XML column, but the property we looking for could be in the first or third SubNode3. The goal is to get all the rows  that contain node /Root/Node2/SubNode3/@property that contains "Reference.Object(ab* (1)). BUT number between () could be another. Here it's a 1 but it could be another number. I wrote * to say the text could be anything else but start with "ab".

What I've tried (among others...) is this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.mycompany.com/validation.xsd')
SELECT *
from [MySchema].[MyTable]
where XML.exist('/Root/Node2/SubNode3/@property[contains(.,"Reference.Object") and contains(.,("(1)"))]') = 1;
```

But here the problem is, I don't know how to say that in (1), the 1 could be another number and that string between first parenthesis in attribute property starts with "ab" and could contain anything.

I also tried with xquery.value to be able to use LIKE syntax, but the problem is that (maybe I missed something) value use a specific node, I mean indexed to [1], so it searched on the first SubNode3 and not the others.

Comment: Personal bug bear, but `;` isn't a "beginninator", it's a terminator. It should go at the end of *all* your statements, not the start of the ones that require the **previous** one to be properly terminated.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm changing that, thank you